# triggers - using the inserted / deleted tables in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, trigger, dynamic-sql, sql-clr

Within a trigger, I'm trying to create a unique table name (using the `NEWID()`) which I can store the data that is found in the inserted and deleted tables.

```sql
Declare @NewID varchar(50) = Replace(convert(Varchar(50),NEWID()),'-','')
Declare @SQLStr varchar(8000)
Set @SQLStr= 'Select * into [TMPIns' + @newID + '] from inserted'
Exec (@SQLStr)
```

I get the following error: Invalid object name 'inserted'

I know I can do:

```sql
Select * into #inserted from inserted
Set @SQLStr= 'Select * into [TMPIns' + @newID + '] from #inserted'
Exec (@SQLStr)
```

But I don't want to use TempDB as these tables can become big and I also feel that it is redundant. Is there a way to avoid the creation of #inserted?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What are you going to do with the TMPIns... table after you have populated it with all of the data from inserted?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using? Is this only going to be used on one table? Or is the "TMPIns" just a generic prefix for the question, but you plan on using table-name specific prefixes to distinguish? And do you have an UpdatedDate or some date field in the table? If not, there is no sense of chronology without looking at the table creation date. Creating a table for each INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE statement is not wise as I believe it requires a schema-lock to create the table. Have you looked into Change Tracking or Change Data Capture?

Comment: This is just part of an auditing SQL Service Broker System... It's a trigger that calls a procedure to send messages.  I tried to send XML messages passing XML inserted and deleted to a procedure, but performance was very poor.  So now, I'm letting the trigger create 2 unique Tables (tmpins and Tmpdel) and send the reference in the message.  The procedure that processes the Queue takes the references and uses the existing tables to audit the changes.  The performance is much better but I want to minimize the load in the trigger.

Comment: I assume this question "[Trigger to create a variable Table to be sent to service broker](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120073/30859)" is this same project. Why has it not been mentioned? There is a lot more info in that question that would have really helped put this into context.

Comment: "The procedure that processes the Queue takes the references and uses the existing tables to audit the changes." How is it that the receiver of the messages has access to those tables? Is it on the same system, or using a Linked Server? How many tables are you auditing? Are you tracking changes in all fields or just some? Have you looked into Change Data Capture?

Comment: I see from your other question that you are using SQL Server Express, which is why you can't use CDC. Ok. I still need to know what version of SQL Server you are on, and am still curious as to why you are using Service Broker.

Comment: The solution has to work for all versions of SQL Server from SQL 2005 to SQL 2016... Express and other.  I'm using the service Broker to lighten the trigger process and release the transaction as soon as possible... The processing will be done by the Service Broker.

Comment: I just noticed your earlier post... I didn't want to confuse people and make the post more complicated than it should be... yes, it is the same project.

Comment: "How is it that the receiver of the messages has access to those tables?" is exactly what i want to do... I want make the inserted and deleted tables visible to the Service Broker.  The same trigger will be for maybe 5 to 10 tables (either with pointing to different TMPIns and TMPDel tables) which will then do the auditing on a different Auditing DB on the same system.

Comment: @JohnGhali Just FYI, you need to specify someone's `@` name in order for them to know that you made a comment, unless you are commenting on their question or answer, then they see those no matter what.

Comment: So you are using Service Broker not to move the data to another system, but to make a more asynchronous process on the same system, right? If that is the case, then you aren't saving anything by using Service Broker since you are still dumping the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables into real tables. Adding Service Broker into this just over-complicates the whole thing. Although I will say that the SQLCLR code I provided will work across all versions of SQL Server starting with 2005, and all editions. But still, I think the process could be improved well beyond this.

Comment: @srutzky "...right?" Yes you are right... more asynchronous... How do you see it?... You got my attention and curiosity!!!  Different ideas can only be beneficial to  learn different ways of doing things.  I never say no to different ideas.

Comment: I just added a comment on my answer regarding further discussion. I think a new, more general question should be posted. Showing what you currently have, stating the environment and restrictions, and stating what the actual end-goal is (which is not implementation specific: auditing does not imply a particular means of doing it). Please post the question link here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more insight into the intended goal of this request, it certainly seems as though even with this immediate issue solved, the working code might not provide anything truly useful. Some concerns are:

- Depending on how many tables this Trigger will be placed on and/or how frequent the DML operations are, this could cause minor performance issues in the database(s) where this Trigger is creating the tables because creating tables requires a Schema-Lock (I believe) and doing that too frequently might complicate some other operations.
- If this Trigger will be placed on more than one Table, how will you distinguish the operations between the different Tables (unless giving them their own prefix for the dynamically created tables)?
- Do you have an `UpdatedDate` or some date field in the table? If not, there is no sense of chronology without looking at the table creation date.
- How do you plan to clean up all of these various tables? Maybe it would be best to create a Schema just to hold these tables?
- Do you plan on indicating anywhere the DML operation that took place?
- If you want to track the "before" and "after" values on an `UPDATE`, then you need to capture both `inserted` and `deleted` tables. But if they have GUID-based names, then you won't be able to correlate between the "inserted" and "deleted" copy tables for a particular UPDATE operation. You would have to re-use the same GUID value and denote the "insert" or "delete" in the table name prefix. If you weren't dynamically creating the table, then you could include a column specifying the DML action, dump both `inserted` and `deleted` tables into the already existing table, and just use a GUID or INT from a Sequence to correlate between 2 rows of the same `UPDATE` operation.
- Depending on what version and edition of SQL Server you are using, you might want to look into [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) and [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx).

However, all of that being said, the issue of interacting with the `inserted` and `deleted` tables via Dynamic SQL is an interesting problem. Unfortunately, it can't be done in T-SQL. So now it's also a challenge :-). Fortunately, this can actually be done. How so? With a little help from our friend, Mr SQLCLR.

Now, there doesn't seem to be a lot of situations that really demand, or even benefit from, SQLCLR Triggers. They seem to be the least useful things you can create with SQLCLR. However, here we have a scenario that they are a wonderful fit for. SQL submitted from SQLCLR code is Dynamic SQL. And SQLCLR Triggers have access to the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, so it would seem that SQLCLR Triggers can access the `inserted` and `deleted` tables in Dynamic SQL. Below is the code that does exactly that to accomplish this request (please note that the DB connection is using the in-process "Context Connection", so the Assembly can be marked with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`; no need for an Asymmetric Key or to set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`):

**Test table for the Trigger to be created on (if using Visual Studio / SSDT, the table definition has to be included in the project):**

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableThatHasTriggers
(
   TableThatHasTriggersID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
                          CONSTRAINT [PK_TableThatHasTriggers] PRIMARY KEY, 
   InsertTime DATETIME NOT NULL
              CONSTRAINT [DF_TableThatHasTriggers_InsertTime] DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
   SomeValue NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NULL
);
```

**The SQLCLR C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class Triggers
{
    [SqlTrigger(Target = "TableThatHasTriggers", Event = "FOR INSERT, UPDATE")]
    public static void tr_TableThatHasTriggers_audit()
    {
        string _AuditSQL = @"
                SELECT ins.*
                INTO   dbo.[TMPIns_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + @"]
                FROM   INSERTED ins;
";

        SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true");
        SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand();
        _Command.CommandText = _AuditSQL;

        // SqlContext.Pipe.Send(_AuditSQL); // display query for debugging purposes ONLY

        try
        {
            _Connection.Open();
            _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            _Command.Dispose();
            _Connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**T-SQL wrapper object to place the SQLCLR Trigger onto the Table:**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_TableThatHasTriggers_SQLCLRaudit]
  ON [dbo].[TableThatHasTriggers]
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
  AS EXTERNAL NAME
             [InsertedTableViaDynamicSQL].[Triggers].[tr_TableThatHasTriggers_SQLCLRaudit];
```

Comment: As suggested, created a more general post to get different views... [Is there a better way to audit given my restrictions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120248/is-there-a-better-way-to-audit-given-my-restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

(Some years later....)

Actually what the the thread title describes CAN be done with T-SQL under the condition that you sensibly can do the processing of the inserted with a cursor.

That is: It IS allowed to create a cursor accessing [Inserted] and then pass that name to the dynamic code.
You can even have the dynamic sql do all the open, while, fetch, close and deallocate stuff.

So in the example from the OP this would not be good, but in the case of a more complex trigger traversing the inserted one by one to do stuff, this could be a very real solution.